# Question in Fubini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading Stein's analysis, and I am including what's on his textbook. The context is $\mathbb R^d = \mathbb R^{d_1} \times \mathbb R^{d_2}$. Suppose $\{f_k\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions on $\mathbb R^d$ that satisfy:

1. The slice $f^y$ is integrable on $\mathbb R^{d_1}$.
2. The function defined by $\int_{R^{d_1}} f^y(x) dx$ is integrable on $\mathbb R^{d_2}$.
3. $\int \int f(x,y) dx dy = \int_{\mathbb R^d}f $.

Suppose $f_k \nearrow f$ is a sequence of nonnegative functions. Our goal is to prove that $f$ satisfies three properties above. For each $k \in\mathbb N$, there exists $A_k$ with $m(A_k) = 0$ , where if $y \in \mathbb (R^{d_2} \setminus A_k)$, then $f_k^y(x)$ is integrable on $\mathbb R^{d_1}$. Letting $A := \cup_k A_k$, $m(A) = 0$ and $f_k$ is integrable on $(\mathbb R^{d_2} \setminus A)$. By an application of MCT,
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb R^d} f_k(x,y)dxdy = \int_{\mathbb R^d} f(x,y) dxdy$$ holds. Let $g_k(y) := \int_{\mathbb R^{d_1}} f_k^y(x) dx$ and $g(y) = \int_{\mathbb R^{d_1}} f^y(x)dx$.  (And the proof continues)

**Question:** Stein claims that $g_k \nearrow g$ by MCT, but I don't see why it is true. If $y \in (\mathbb R^{d_2} \setminus A)$, why do I necessarily have $f_k^y \nearrow f^y$ for almost every $x \in \mathbb R^{d_1}$?

Comment: It is true for every $x$, not just almost every $x$. Write down the definition of $f^{y}_ k(x)$ to see why this is true.

Comment: Ok, since I said $f_k \nearrow f$ (for every ($(x,y) \in \mathbb R^d$), what you said is true. If I replace the statement by: $f_k \nearrow f$ for a.e. $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^d$, is the statement still true?

Comment: Yes, it is true. If a set $E$ has measure $0$ in $\mathbb R^{2}$ then almost all sections $E_x$ have measure $0$ in $\mathbb R$